# How do installers perform delayed writes on system restarts

Tags: installation, uninstallation

I have a need to delay the deleting and/or modifying of files to either just before the system shuts down, or right before it fully boots up.  The reason being is that I have binaries that are currently loaded in several other processes, and those files are locked until those processes shutdown. This is a common problem that installers have to face all the time.  I believe they they simply have the file changes happen on startup (or maybe shutdown) after most processes have stopped running to insure that nothing has their assemblies loaded.  How do you perform these delayed file copies programatically?